# Recognize spatio-temporal patterns correlating with events

Tags: predictive-models, pattern-recognition, spatio-temporal

I am trying to recognize a spatio-temporal pattern in my spatio-temporal input sequence X. The occurrence of the pattern is roughly temporally correlated with another event E1.

For example I have training data of this kind:

```
...0010010000100001001001000010000001000000010010000... x1 \
...0001001000100000000001000000000001000000100001000... x2  |- X
...0010000000010000100010000010000010000000000010000... x3 /
...0001000001000000000000100000000100000000000000010... E1
------- time ------>
```

I have training data that contains inputs X and E1.
I need a predictor for E1 given X.

In the example, the predictor should learn, that E1 gets triggered, if all three components of X are active within temporal vicinity. In the training data, E1 is not super accurately timed, but can happen some time before or after the optimal point in time.

Which algorithms would you suggest?

PS: X might also be a real signal instead of just binary.